# Multiple user accessing single table

Tags: php, mysql, multi-user

I am looking for some general advice. I currently have a database (using PHP, apache and MYSQL) that runs as such:

1. User uploads data to the DB, stored in table 1.
2. User uploads more data to the DB, stored in table 2.
3. User runs a query for the two tables to be cross referenced and the result stored in table 3.
4. Table 3 is processed and the resulting information is stored in table 4.
5. Tables 1, 2 and 3 are deleted (ready for the next upload/cross reference).

The details of how the DB works is academic. The problem I have is that there can be multiple users of the DB logged in at any one time. This leads to the problem that if one user is currently processing data in table 3 (Step 4) and another user runs the cross referencing query (Step 3) the information being used by the first user will be overridden by the new data. Table 4 is a 'cache' of results that is constantly growing so shouldn't be affected by multiple users adding to it at once (the table uses a auto_increment field so there should be no issues of duplicate records).

Does anyone have any general ideas on how this could be accomplished? The site needs to allow for up to 50 users (ideally) with around 5-10 on at anyone time.

Creating a separate table for each user seems like a waste of space and effort (not to mentioned updating them all with new code!). I thought of creating 'one time use' tables (perhaps linked off the users login name?) that would be create as the files are uploaded, used and then deleted once it has all been complete. Is this good practice or would this lead to further issues.

This is the first website/database I have deployed so I'm not too sure about good practices/pitfalls. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Why multiple tables and not simply multiple rows in the same table? You could index into the tables using the login name or PHP session id.

Comment: Do you really need database tables for this process? Can you store the data in files and do the processing in-memory?

Comment: You could always [lock your tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) but that seems like a workaround for what (appears) is a design problem.  Certainly you could find a better way of doing this without so much work on the database.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database      Have a look.

Comment: @Halcyon I'm not sure what you mean by processing in memory? As I said this is the first time working with databases. Do you have any documentation you could refer me to? Thanks

Comment: @Crackertastic Could you possibly refer me to a solution? Or at least expand on the main design flaw of the system?

Comment: @robbiecutting I mean not using databases at all. The process you describe is not a good fit for a database management system. That can indicate that databases are not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @robbiecutting From a look over the answers below it looks like you got your solution.  But what I was referring to (that Halcyon has mentioned) is that databases didn't seem to be what would best fit in with what you are trying to do.  From your description it looked like the tables where short term caches for data, in which case things like flat files or maybe even sessions would be right for the job.  For me, when I think databases, I'm also thinking persistent storage needs(well....for the most part).

Comment: @Halcyon Oh I see, given the nature of the systems I think a DB is the correct choice. I haven't describe this in the post, so my apologies. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Crackertastic The data in Table 1 + 2 is also cross referenced, processed and stored before the above process is initiated. I avoided mentioning it so as to not confuse the above method. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you add a column for **UserID** or **UserName** that references users table and that way you will have multiple rows in that table but identified by users. Make sure to add index to userID column.

Also you should be using **InnoDB** engine since it uses **RowLevel** locking instead of **TableLocking** which **MyISAM** does.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked such a simple solution! I'll give it a go. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

You can lock rows for entire transaction, forbidding anyone to interact with them, this could be done with InnoDB table type, or alternatively you can lock entire table on MyISAM table type.

You can find info [on official mysql docs page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html)

**2.**

Hold some unique user identifiers (and/or timestamp) in table 1 and 2 and flush them occasionally by those columns.

**3**

MYSQL have special syntax to do transactions, consider them as bunch of SQL queries, running in background and storing result in temporary space, and saving data only after all actions was completed.

[Here's the link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

**4**

If using temporary tables is not mandatory, it's better to process such kind of logic besides SQL server, for ex on C++, java or PHP. Writing/selecting/flushing a large of temporary data on SQL is not very performance-wise.